# How to remove warnings in console from Gramarly in my angular project: Using DEFAULT root logger; Using default timeseries implementation

Tags: angularjs, console

In Chrome I use Grammarly for writing grammarly correct texts.
These warnings appeared on my angular project in console:

[DEFAULT]: WARN : Using DEFAULT root logger
[WARNING] Using default timeseries implementation.

Tell me how to remove them?
Or is it a problem on their part?

These are warnings in console:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I have the "Grammarly" Chrome extension, and I see these warnings in all the sites youtube, google, even here...
After removing it ,these warning have been removed